# Filling containers by volume given a bucket size

Tags: r, bucket

Suppose I have a dataset of serially numbered containers and their respective volumes.

```
x <- data.frame("SN" = 1:3, "Price" = c(10,20,30), "Volume" = c(100,150,200))

SN     Price      Volume
1      10         100
2      20         150
3      30         200
```

I am looking to fill the containers using a bucket of a given size.

1. If the container is filled before the bucket is emptied, I'd like to
   move to the next SN.
2. If the bucket is emptied before the container
   is filled, I'd like to start a new row with the remaining container.

Desired output with bucket_size = 200:

```
 SN     Price      Volume
    1      10         100 # max for SN 1 is 100, totally filled, bucket now = 100
    2      20         100 # max for SN 2 is 150, bucket now = 0 
    2      20          50 # fill remaining SN 2, new bucket now = 150 
    3      30         150 # max for SN 3 is 200, bucket now = 0
    3      30          50 # fill remaining in SN 3, bucket now = 150 remaining
```

I have started coding but it seems my code not generic enough to work for any bucket size.

```
x <- data.frame("SN" = 1:3, "Price" = c(10,20,30), "Volume" = c(100,150,200))

bucketsize <- 200
PendingBucketVolume <- bucketsize

y <- data.frame(SN = integer(),Price=numeric(),Volume=numeric(),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
  if (x$Volume[i] <= PendingBucketVolume) {
    print(x$Volume[i])
    PendingBucketVolume <- PendingBucketVolume - x$Volume[i]
  } else {
    print(PendingBucketVolume)
    remainder <- x$Volume[i] - PendingBucketVolume
    if (remainder <= bucketsize) {
      print(remainder)
    } else {
      print(bucketsize)
      remainder <- remainder - bucketsize

    }

    if (remainder < PendingBucketVolume) {
      PendingBucketVolume <- remainder
    } else {
      PendingBucketVolume <- bucketsize
      PendingBucketVolume <- PendingBucketVolume - remainder
    }

  }
}
```

Suggestions to make it generic and efficient.

Comment: why does sn 1 not get expanded? why does sn 3 in your desired output show 150? also where did sn 4 come from?

Comment: @Shree based on my understanding, it looks like SN 1 does not get expanded because its entire 100 volume is satisfied by the bucket size. However, I don't know why SN 4 wouldn't be SN 3.

Comment: @EvanFriedland nope, still don't get it. Looks like the post has been edited and I am even more confused now. Anyways, looks like your answer met their requirement so I'll probably move on.

Comment: I edited the post so I hope I didn't just fit my answer to look better. What are you confused about for SN 1? What would you expect to happen?

Comment: Hey @Shree, This is just the sample data set. I am trying to implement Volume bucketing to calculate VPIN. In volume bucketing, we group sequential trades into equal volume buckets of an exogenously defined size V. A volume bucket is a collection of trades that, combined, add up to a volume V. If the last trade needed to complete a bucket is for a size greater than needed, the excess size is given to the next bucket.

Comment: Thanks @EvanFriedland Suggest approach works perfectly for the sample dataset but on my actual dataset its taking long time and I am getting error - 'Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)'. Do you have any suggestion for its performance improvement.

Comment: Trying to write up the if else version of this which would be faster has me scratching my head. Wondering if it’s a bin packing problem... my solution only handles whole numbers - and makes some really lengthy vectors if your data is long...

Comment: Found the same concept implemented in SAS here - Trying to do the same in R https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067853/sas-creating-a-dynamic-interval/11068099#11068099

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: Thanks @EvanFriedland. It works well with the sample data. Will adjust it to make it work for my actual data.

Comment: let me know if you have any issues - this VPIN stuff is pretty interesting

Comment: I added an additional edit - might be of interest to you

Comment: @EvanFriedland ..Thanks for sharing the insights..definitely interesting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent way too long trying to get `if else` logic to work for this. There was too much balancing of row volumes and bucket volumes. Instead, I figured I could just break all the volumes out and assign them an ID, `cbind` them, and then use table to bring them back together. The result is probably a much slower calc than the `if else` method, but very simple to code.

```
x <- data.frame("SN" = 1:3, "Price" = c(10,20,30), "Volume" = c(100,150,200))

allocate_buckets <- function(x, bucketsize){
  # assumption that X has the colnames
  stopifnot(colnames(x) == c("SN","Price","Volume"))
  row_num <- rep(x[,"SN"], x[,"Volume"])
  l <- length(row_num)
  bucket_num <- rep(1:ceiling(l/bucketsize), each = bucketsize)[1:l]
  out <- table(row_num, bucket_num)
  out.ind <- which(out !=0, arr.ind = T)
  return(cbind.data.frame(x[out.ind[,1],c("SN","Price")], Volume = out[out.ind]))
}
```

So now you can use it for any (whole number) volume:

```
allocate_buckets(x, 200)
#    SN Price Volume
#1    1    10    100
#2    2    20    100
#2.1  2    20     50
#3    3    30    150
#3.1  3    30     50

allocate_buckets(x, 67)
#    SN Price Volume
#1    1    10     67
#1.1  1    10     33
#2    2    20     34
#2.1  2    20     67
#2.2  2    20     49
#3    3    30     18
#3.1  3    30     67
#3.2  3    30     67
#3.3  3    30     48
```

**EDIT**

Amazing link you posted, I was so close to this, here is the R version:

```
x <- data.frame("SN" = 1:3, "Price" = c(10,20,30), "Volume" = c(100,150,200))
y <- data.frame(SN = integer(), Price = numeric(), Volume = numeric())
bucket <- bucketsize <- 200
vol <- numeric()
count <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  volume <- x[i,"Volume"]
  while(volume!=0){
    vol <- min(volume, bucket)
    print(vol)
    count <- count + 1
    y[count,] <- x[i,]
    y[count,"Volume"] <- vol
    volume <- volume - vol
    bucket <- bucket - vol
    if(bucket == 0){
      bucket <- bucketsize
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2**
I ran a microbenchmark test (took a while) on the two methods and the result was that my original method actually seems faster compared to the code transcribed from SAS.

```
                     expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 allocate_buckets(x, 200) 312.4177  466.6347  504.2121  483.1754  516.2977  846.4529   100
            other(x, 200) 986.6495 1233.5141 1339.4219 1265.3606 1389.1158 2023.7884   100
```

This was unexpected to me. The benefit of the other method is that it can handle non-integer values. One could probably speed up the allocate_buckets function by using data.tables and the non-integer constraint could be lifted by multiplying by 100 or whatever number makes the smallest decimal become a whole number, and then dividing the result by 100 afterwards.